# Histogram for to classify five colors is not giving proper results in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have samples of five types: **Red, Orange, Green, Yellow, Blue**. I have written a code to create histogram. But in the output, blue is perceived as red and actually all the values doesn't seem to be correct.

I want to remove the affect of white and black pixels so, i am eliminating the pixel which are white or black through a "if condition" i.e. if(saturation>50 && V>50) then only use that pixel for histogram.

**Example of my Images:**

[image]

My code for a normalized histogram with 5 bins is following:

```
    void getHistogram(Mat input, MatND& hist_input)
    {

        float totalNumPixels = 0;
        int h_bins = 5;
        int h_range = 179;
        hist_input = Mat::zeros(1, h_bins, CV_32FC1);



        Mat hsv_input;
        hsv_input.create( input.rows, input.cols, CV_8UC3);
        cvtColor(input, hsv_input, CV_RGB2HSV);
        cout<<"done upto here \n";
        Mat channels[3];
        split( hsv_input, channels);

        for(int i=0; i<channels[0].rows; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<channels[0].cols; j++)
            {
                if (   (int)channels[1].at<uchar>(i,j)>50     &&     (int)channels[2].at<uchar>(i,j)>50   )
                {
                    totalNumPixels++;
                    int pixelValue = (int)channels[0].at<uchar>(i,j);
                    int correspondingBin = (pixelValue*h_bins)/h_range;

                    hist_input.at<float>(0, correspondingBin) = hist_input.at<float>(0, correspondingBin) + 1; 
                }
            }
        }


        for(int j=0; j<hist_input.cols; j++)
        {

                float pixelValue = hist_input.at<float>(0,j);       
                hist_input.at<float>(0, j) = hist_input.at<float>(0, j) /  totalNumPixels; 
        }   

    }
```

Comment: why don't you try taking the median color or even apply a big gaussian filter just to get a "representative" color (or even get a mean color) and then check only the Hue value in the HVS colorspace? I haven't tested it but it seems it will work...

Comment: @sepdek: even my code is working but the problem is that blue is usually perceived as red....i can see that if i take 10 bins then for each sample the distribution among bins is different....but see i am getting this for blue: `0.8936,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0064,0.084`

Comment: OpenCV work in BGR colorspace (not RGB). Is that your problem?

Comment: not really...doesn't the values i have obtained above for bule color image seems wrong to you?...why am i getting maximum value "0.8936" for the first bin?...first should have maximum value if the image is "red"..isn't it?

Comment: Normally, if you work in RGB then you get the red component first, but OpenCV works in BGR. Did you check this? Can you check the actual image colors and report them here? I.e use something like photoshop to check the colors and let us know...